# how to delete specific value from array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I can't find out how to delete a specific value from string when clicking on an element with the string value. its for my todo list.

```
if (window.localStorage.fullName !== undefined) {
alert('Your browser does not support localStorage');
} else {
$(function () {
    console.log('localSorage compitability detected. proceeding...');
```

global vars & functions

```
    var tdli = [];
```

add list items

```
    $('#tdladd').click(function () {
        $('.todolist ul ul').append("<li class='tdli'>" + $('#tdlinput').val() + "</li>");
        tdli.push($('#tdlinput').val());
        $('#tdlinput').val('');
        var array = tdli + "";
        localStorage.setItem('tdlis', array);
        console.log(array);
        $('#todolist').hide().fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

remove list items

```
    $('li').click(function () {
        var itemtoRemove = $(this);
        tdli.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, tdli), 1);
        console.log(tdli);
    });

    $('#clearall').click(function () {
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    });
```

load list items

```
    var tdlitems = localStorage.getItem('tdlis');

    var array = tdlitems.split(',');

    tdli.push(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] + "<br>";
        $('.todolist ul ul').append("<li>" + array[i] + "</li>");
    };

    console.log(array);


});

}
```

Comment: Could you post ALL of your relevant code?  It's possible, but I want to write an answer that fits your code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `tdli` is a jQuery wrapped set (which itself is an array-like-object), it will have *DOM* nodes stored instead of another jQuery objects. That means, just go like

```
var itemtoRemove = this;
```

and you should be fine.

---

After you posted your complete code, we can see you're actually pushing `string values` into your `tdli` Array, but you try to `.splice()` objects respectively `DOM nodes`, which of course doesn't make any sense at all (comparing apples to oranges).